# wp_query on search results page showing all results every time

Tags: php, wp-query, query

I am trying to build my search results page, and I am using wp_query.  However, overtime I search something all of my posts are showing up instead of only those posts that match the search.  Why is this, and how can I fix this?

```html
<?php 
get_header(); ?>
<?php 
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 4
);
$search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<div class="search-results-search">
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form-search form-inline-search" action="">
            <div class="input-group-search">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm-search search-field-search form-control-search" placeholder="<?php echo $s ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : $search_query->the_post() ?>
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article>
<?php endwhile ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>Ooops, no posts here!</h2>
<?php endif ?>


<?php
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the code above is the cause of the issue? Are you certain that this template is being called? Maybe there's a `pre_get_posts` in your theme somewhere overwriting your query. What happens if you run `print_r( $search_query ); die();` after your create a new WP_Query()? Can you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/271166/edit) and add in some additional information please?

Comment: you are missing to use the 'search' parameter - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

Comment: How would I add the search parameter in my code?  When I tried adding it, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new WP_Query. As per the template hierarchy WordPress uses the search.php template in your theme for the search results page. This template just needs to contain [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and the only posts inside that will be your search results.

See Twenty Seventeen's search results template as an example: https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/search.php